# Google appengine Send local gif as an email attachment

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, gif, email-attachments

I'm trying to send a local gif as an email attachment on Google appengine. The email will send but without an attachment.

```
message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="My image <whomever@gmail.com>",
subject="image")

message.to = "Jim <whomever@gmail.com>"

message.body = my_body_text

message.html = my_body_html

image = open('./bust.gif', 'r')

attachments=[(image.name, image.read())]

message.send()

image.close()
```

Answer (score 9):

You forgot to set the `attachments` field on your `message`, and made a local variable you didn't use instead. Simply change

```
attachments=[(image.name, image.read())]
```

to

```
message.attachments=[(image.name, image.read())]
```