# Sending mail attachment using Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Can anybody tell me what is the variable "myname" in the query statement doing out there . If for example I want to send a text file "hello.txt" what should I put in the myname variable . And do I need to modify the code if I want to send an image file .

P.S - I am new to this , so please bear with me before downvoting .

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.ext import db

class DocFile(db.Model):
    doc_name = db.StringProperty()
    doc_file = db.BlobProperty()

q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM DocFile WHERE doc_name = :1", myname)
results = q.fetch(1)
if results:
    doc = results[0]
    mail.send_mail(sender="support@example.com",
                  to="Albert Johnson <Albert.Johnson@example.com>",
                  subject="The doc you requested",
                  body="""
Attached is the document file you requested.

The example.com Team
""",
                  attachments=[(doc.doc_name, doc.doc_file)])
```

Answer (score 2):

`myname` is used as a substitute to `:1` in the datastore query, to find the `DocFile` entity which doc_name property is equal to the value of `myname`.

It has little to do with how the `send_mail` function works and is only here to illustrate the example.

You can attach any file to an email, the `attachments` parameter accept a list of tuple of string (for the filename), and byte string (for the data).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I got that sir ; but I need a little bit more help .                  q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM DocFile WHERE doc_name = :1", myname)      Should I simply keep the field myname = None , such as q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM DocFile WHERE doc_name = :1", None) . And as for sending "hello.txt" , I guess I do not have to hardcode any value to the parameter of attachments[(doc.doc_name,doc.doc_file)].So how does it know which file I want to change . Umm... little bit of help required here .

Comment: I am hoping an answer of this sort http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526272/google-appengine-send-local-gif-as-an-email-attachment